# jQuery form manipulation

Tags: jquery, css, forms, jquery-selectors

Using jQuery, and the following example form code from [Line25 website](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-stylish-contact-form-with-html5-css3):

```
<div id="contact"> 
<h1>Send an email</h1> 
<form action="#" method="post"> 
    <fieldset> 
        <label for="name">Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" /> 
        
        <label for="email">Email:</label> 
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" /> 
        
        <label for="message">Message:</label> 
        <textarea id="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?"></textarea> 
        
        <input type="submit" value="Send message" /> 
        
    </fieldset> 
</form> 
</div>
```

How can I go about making the "Name" label input above:

1. read only/disabled and also set background colour to yellow
2. show/hide this form item on the web page based on a condition
3. read only/disabled but still allow the user to place cursor in the cell and move cursor left/right.
4. When the user tabs/moves into each field in the above example, highlight the the field, perhaps a border colour around the field indicating that this is the active field.

Comment: Please split the question into 4. Or use Google to search for them individually.

Comment: Well, how much have you done yourself? http://jquery.com/ is a good starting point, which has lots of examples. Right now, it looks like you just want to find somebody that will do all the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a form input element disabled like this:

```
$("#name").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

To set a background color, make a CSS class:

```
input.disabled { background-color: yellow; }
```

Then do:

```
$("#name").attr("disabled", "disabled").addClass("disabled");
```

You can hide the form like this:

```
$("#contact").hide();
```

A condition might be that a button is clicked:

```
$("#buttonid").click(function() { $("#contact").toggle(); });
```

Note that if that form has validation and you hide only some of the input elements and leave the submit button visible, the form won't submit unless validation is disabled on the hidden elements.

You can make an input element readonly:

```
$("#name").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

Finally, to achieve 4, create CSS class:

```
input:active { border: solid 1px red; }
```